# Mysql installation problems

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install mysql-server-5.6 package, but I have this error message:

```
root@ps481138:/home/nikitasorokin# apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server-5.6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 941 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.25-0ubuntu1) ...
stop: Unknown instance: 
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Apt-cache result:

```
root@ps481138:/home/nikitasorokin# apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.6
mysql-server-5.6:
  Installed: 5.6.25-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.6.25-0ubuntu1
   Version table:
  *** 5.6.25-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Additional info:

```
lsb_release -a; uname -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise

Linux ps481138 3.1.9-vs2.3.2.5vs2.3.2.5+ #3 SMP Wed Feb 12 13:51:29  PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What do you think about the reasons of this error and how can I fix it?
Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: It is not fully installed as states it apt-get message: `1 not fully installed or removed.`

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.6`

Comment: and `lsb_release -a; uname -a`

Comment: Sorry, again my bad `lsb_release -a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you **CAN'T** install this Ubuntu Wily package in Ubuntu Precise. And sorry again for this short answer and to be the harbinger of bad news :\

Remove the Wily repositories in your system.

Comment: Should I start a new question, if I have problems with mysql installation after removing Willy packages?

Comment: Are you on Precise or on Wily (15.10). Your system says Precise (12.04)

Comment: I'm on Precise, that is correct.

Comment: You can't use Wily repositories in Precise. You should ask a new question: "Install mysql server 5.6 in Precise"